# Setting Columns Width in Excel with C# VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm using C# for a VSTO Excel Add In.

Currently I'm setting the columns to be auto fitted with:

```
newWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

How can I set the Column width to have some additional padding?

In psuedocode it would be:

```
Column.Width = columnCurrentWidth + 10
```

For a certain column, make it a bit wider than the auto fit width

I've figure out how to get the width of a column but not set it

```
int width = ((Excel.Range)newWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2]).Width;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `ColumnWidth` and `RowHeight` of `Range`.

This should work:

```
int width = ((Excel.Range)newWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2]).Width;
((Excel.Range)newWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2]).ColumnWidth = width + 10;
```

Comment: I had a mistake in my question; width has to be a double not an int, and its actually ColumnWidth not width. With those two changes your answer works!